# How to make iteration for Newmark method in Mathematica 8

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematica, mathematical-modeling, physics

How to make iteration method for solving differential equations by Newmark method? There are just three equations which describe the Newmark method. I need q for time step for example 0.01. Also, for each time step, it is important to save matrix K0, because matrix K0 depends of q.  You can find attached file here in .nb .pdf

http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/HknBh8LW6csdsUEP5QXOCg

or just copy and paste in your Mathematica sheet from here

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=21aZqrDq

Thank you in advance!

Derdack